# como podria hacer que se vea un texto al pasar el mouse por encima de un picturebox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2013

por favor alguien me podria ayudar. creo que se usa el evento de picturebox **mouse hover**, pero no se como usarlo, ayuda porfavor

Comment: Por favor, incluye el código que hayas intentado y los problemas específicos que te estés encontrando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No tienes porqué hacerlo en el evento `MouseHover`. Puedes asignarle un objeto `ToolTip` al control `PictureBox` en cualquier momento.

Por ejemplo podrías hacerlo en el propio constructor del formulario. Siempre después de la llamada a `InitializeComponent` para asegurarte de que se ha creado el `PictureBox`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var tt=new ToolTip();
    tt.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, "Texto a mostrar");
}
```